# Looping through 2 columns in Pandas DataFrame with and without a specific condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame with more than 11,000 observations. I want to loop through 2 columns from the several columns. below is the 2 columns that I want to loop through:

```
df1:   EWZ        sales_territory
0      90164.0          north
1      246794.0         north
2      216530.0         north
3      80196.0          north
4      12380.0          north

11002   224.0           east
11003   1746.0          east
11004   7256.0          east
11005   439.0           east
11006   13724.0         east
```

The data shown here is the first 5 and last 5 observations of the columns.

The `sales_territory` column has `north`,`south`,`east` and `west` observations. `EWZ` is the population size.

I want to select all `east` that have same value of population and also with `north`, `south`, `west` with same value of population and append in a variable. I.e, if there are 20 `north` that have `20,000` as population size, I want to select them. Same with others.

I tried using `nested if` but frankly speaking, I don't know how to specify the condition for `EWZ` column. I tried `Iterrows()`, but I could not find my way out.

How do I figure this out?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: @Aryerez, I want to have all `east`,`south`,`west`,`north`  with same value of population size in a new column.e.g, if there 201 population size in `10` rows and these match with `east` in the `sales_territory` column, it should be selected. same procedure for `north`,east`,`south`,`west`,

Comment: The conditions are separate for `east`, `north`, `west` and `south.`  what i mean is that if i am looking for `north` that have a population size of say `122.0`, this should only affect `north` and not `south`,`west` ,`east`. each have there separate conditions. but the final result will appended in a variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to use a for loop. You can use:
`df1.groupby(['EWZ', 'sales_territory']).apply(your_function)`
and achieve the desired result. If you want to get a list of unique values then you can just drop duplicates using  `df1[['EWZ', 'sales_territory']].drop_duplicates()`

If you don't care about the EWZ values while selecting you can use 4 loc statements like

```
df1.loc[df1['sales_territory'] == 'north', 'new_column'] = value
df1.loc[df1['sales_territory'] == 'east', 'new_column'] = value
df1.loc[df1['sales_territory'] == 'south', 'new_column'] = value  
df1.loc[df1['sales_territory'] == 'west', 'new_column'] = value
```

Comment: what does `value` signify?

Comment: whatever you want to add to those columns

Comment: i used `df1.groupby(['EWZ', 'sales_territory']).apply(your_function)`